# how to display content pages in mvc using content management system?

Tags: model-view-controller, content-management-system

I have this route configure in my route config file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CMS",
                "CMS/{id}/{title}",
                new { controller = "CMS", action = "Index" },
                namespaces: new[] { "abc.def.Web.Controllers" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "abc.def.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

The issue is it will properly display first request i-e `example.com/cms/86b537d5-84a9-43a2-8736-0ff08aa44ae4/contentone`
But when I click on second link of cms it will give error as below.
Url generated is `example.com/cms/cms/86b537d5-84a9-43a2-8736-0ff08aa44ae4/contenttwo`

error is : 404. Can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: Where are those the first and the second links are located? On separate pages? Do you display some kind of a list on a single page? Could you please add the code of your page where you show those links? It will help to solve your issue.

Comment: I have resolve this issue.. It was like this before <a href="../@item.PagePath">@item.MenuName</a> which it search in cuurent directory and I have changed to <a href="/@item.PagePath">@item.MenuName</a> which it searches from root directory.